# wifi connection problem in hp pavillion g6

Tags: wireless, hp

I have HP Pavilion G6-2202TX and have installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8; but it does not connect to WiFi inspite of being connected in Windows 8.

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: have you installed drivers for wifi?

Answer (score 0):

You need kind of network manager .. with GUI (graphic) or just command mode.
take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/248806/82136)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I could not get any Internet to update drivers, and update Ubuntu all together.

I plugged it in, updated everything and it seemed to work fine. I have a hp pavili G6 1c58dx.

Hope this solves your problem. It was pretty staight forward for me. You could also install gnome GUI and see if this sovles your problem. This also helped fix my HDMI problem and a few others!