# No Internet, but Wifi connection after Update to Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) from 13.10

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, drivers, ath9k

I updated recently to 14.04 from 13.10, everything seemed to work fine, but after the second reboot the system connects to the network, but no internet is working.

I tried already plenty of solutions from Askubuntu.com, but nothing seems to work.

My computer is a ACER Aspire V5-573G. I am using an Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wifi-Network card (PCI).

I did already the following:

- I downloaded the newest backports, copied it to my system and tried to install them with: "make defconfig-ath9k" and also "make defconfig-rtlwifi", but it didn't help, yet.
- I checked rfkill, but everything fine there.
- I changed the wifi channel to 1, did't help.
- I added to modprobe (ath9k.conf) the following line "nohwcrypt=1 blink=1 btcoex_enable=1"

My system is as actual as it could be, so no header download necessary.

After several reboots and further tweaking I can't even find my wifi in the menu now, it vanished, I guess that's not a good sign. Damn it I am totally lost.

So, please help.

Best regards,

Tom

---

Note: I also did the following in the terminal: sudo sed -i '/exit 0/i iwconfig wlan0 rate  11M' /etc/rc.local

Comment: Do you use dhcp? Can you reach your router? What is your ifconfig output?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to incomplete updating try to connect to the wifi from command line, following links will guide you how to do that.

[How do I connect to a WPA wifi network using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line)

[iwconfig usage for WEP access point?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149411/iwconfig-usage-for-wep-access-point)

If you are able to connect it will identify the problem was in updates. Then you can use `sudo apt-get update` and subsequently `upgrade` to take care of the issue

Comment: I am pretty sure that this error is due to update errors

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

change managed=false to managed=true.

From the top-right corner select Edit Connections, and add a new connection. Specify your ip address, netmask, gateway, and the DNS server being 8.8.8.8.

Then add these two lines to /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Then run:

sudo service network-manager restart.

**Else try the following**

```
gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add the below lines to the file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Hope this helps!